# SQL Server 2012 intellisense works for first query in a window

Tags: sql, intellisense

My problem is that when I write a query in sql server on a sheet I get intellisense for the first query and only the first.

If I was to write a query directly below the first, I get no intellisense at all. I could put my cursor back to the initial query and get intellisense once again.

For example, this is a single query sheet:

```
select t.* from table1 t; --Intellisense, yay!

select t.* from table2 t2; --no intellisense, ;(
```

What is going on here? I have turned off SQLCMD Mode, I read this will mess up the intellisense, also I have changed the maximum script size around - all to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: not sure if it will work but try separating the two queries with a "GO"

Comment: Try CTRL+SHIFT+R when you are on the second line.

Comment: Does it work with CTRL+SHIFT+R?

Comment: ctrl + shift + r does not help. thanks for the suggestion. this is happening to our entire dev room -.-.

Comment: We recently moved from using virtual machines to our local machines last week. This is an issue that has surfaced as a result of our move.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is SSMS reads the second query as an error. I know you can comment out the top one and get intellisense on the bottom on. Really sucks when you have a huge server.

Comment: I did not say it will not run both. I said sql will not recognize it until it runs. try writing xml you get the same problem. If it did not work for you then fine, but did you try it?

Comment: Agree with Calvin Smith. If I comment the first query and intellisense works on second query but why is this happening and what is the solution to the problem?

Comment: @VVV great question, and that I don't know, but if you figure it out let me know.

Comment: I found the problem and the solution to it. Intellisense works now. Installing VS 2010 SP1 breaks intellisense. To fix it you need to install latest SQL server service pack. In my case I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 service pack 3 and intellisense is working now. Have a look at this - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2531482

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a remote server you as many people that use SSMS 2012 have to wait a patch from Microsoft.

Otherwise [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2591/troubleshooting-intellisense-in-sql-server-management-studio-2012/) you can find a list of setup to check.

Best regards,
Danny

Answer (score 0):

One possibility - If you have installed Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 then it will definitely break SQL server intellisense. To resolve the issue install the latest service pack for your SQL server. Read this article here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2531482